# Session Variable as Condition in Association in CakePHP Model

Tags: cakephp, session-variables

i searched a lot, but i'm helpless.
i try to use a sessionvariable as condition in a hasMany association inside a model.
like this (in the Model)

```
public $hasMany = array(
'myClassname' => array(
'className'     => 'myClassname',
'foreignKey'    => 'foreignid'
'conditions'    => array('myClassname.id' => <this should be the value of the sessionvariable>),
)
);
```

could somebody give me the clou please?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this condition in your controller just before the find condition:

```
$this->ModelName->bindModel(array('hasMany' => array('myClassname' => array('className' => 'myClassname',
                                                                            'foreignKey' => 'foreignid',
                                                                            'conditions'    => array('myClassname.id' => $this->Session->read('SessionVar'))
                                            ))), false);
```

You can also use this dynamic association-ship in beforeFind() callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a "clou" :)

`$hasMany` is an array therefore it can not have a "dynamic" value, that is one that would change depending on some code.

If you can't do it otherwise (like using appropriate `conditions` in your finds), you will need to use the callback `Model::beforeFind()` to set the current session ID.